# Dom - Create an element with false value

Tags: php, dom

Using Dom, I'm trying to create an element with the value of false. However, when I give it the value of false, it just puts an empty string as the value. I assume this is because the default is false. Is there a way to get around this?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');

$element = $dom->createElement('my_element', false);
$dom->appendChild($element);

var_dump($dom->saveXML());

// returns string(48) "<?xml version="1.0"?><my_element></my_element>"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$element = $dom->createElement('my_element', 'false');
```

The second parameter is a value. `false` is a boolean.

Comment: Miss-understood, modified. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value `false` within `my_element` in generated `xml`, you need write `'false'` because you append a [`string`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) to your element, not a [`boolean`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

As you see from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) `DOMDocument::createElement` has following signature:

```
DOMDocument::createElement ( string $name [, string $value ] )
```

That means that expected second parameter type is [`string`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). When you pass [`boolean`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) as a parameter it will cast into [`string`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). `false` evaluates to an empty string (`string(0) ""`) and `true` to `1` (`string(1) "1"`) when you cast it as [`string`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9vTBQn)).

For more information about [*type juggling*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

**Note:** [*Type juggling*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) is dark side of php so I suggest avoid mixing variable types.

Answer (score 0):

$element = $dom->createElement('my_element', 'false');